# basic understanding of variable assignment in awk

Tags: bash, awk, variable-assignment

I am having a very basic quarrel with my understanding of awk's way of using variable assignment. In the below how come the output from the variable `new` that I assign is not printed - instead the whole record (`$0`) get printed. I did look trough the [GNU user's guide](https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html) but failed to comprehend this very fundamental behavior. Thanks for the patience!

```
echo "a b c" | awk '
{
print $NF #This prints c    
new=$NF
print $new #Why does this not print c 
}'
```

Output:

```
c
a b c
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To understand difference use this code:

```
echo "a b c" | awk '
{
print $NF #This prints c    
new=NF
print $new #Why does this not print c 
}'
```

**Output:**  It correctly prints:

```
c
c
```

When you use `new=$NF` instead of `new=NF` you assign value of last field into `new`. And then when you do `$new` again in `print` statement then `awk` attempts to convert `c` to a number and gets `0` hence it prints whole line.

Comment: Ah ! Never $ for variables on the right side of an assignment (for what I was trying at least).

Comment: @user3375672 Never `$` for variables on **EITHER** side of an assignment. Just never `$` to get the content of variables, that's all, just like C and most other algol-based languages. `$` is an operator to get you the value of a field so just like `a[7]` gets you the value of the array `a[]` indexed by `7`, using `$7` gets you the value of the `7`th field.

Answer (score 0):

You can update the line to print to `print new`; Accessing variables is C-type in awk.

`new=$NF` is same as:
`new=$3` (the value of NF is evaluated to 3)

And now that the variable `new` has the value of 3rd column(`c`), you can use:
`print new`

Else, as per **@anubhava**'s answer, you can assign the value of `NF` to `new` and use it with the `$` symbol to print the 3rd column.

Answer (score 0):

It is tempting to associate the $ with strings, as some languages use this convention.  Furthermore, shells such as bash use the $ to retrieve a variable value.  And the most confusing thing is, both the shell and awk use $ with a number to parse fields from a complete line. So $1 contains the first field, and so on.  But nowhere else do variables in awk use the dollar sign.